# How to make sub arrays tied up with one main ID and then allow that ID be selected multiple times

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a concern. I'm creating shopping cart like system. I need to store information of car selected as an array. Each car can have multiple addon items. And each addon item will have their own array of info.So I need to have sub array inside the main array. Then I will store them inside session like this:

```
$_SESSION['info'][$car_id] = array(
  'car_info'=>$variable,
  array('addons'=>$variable
));
```

If I set $car_id as the key , I found that the same car_id cannot be selected again.If I omit the $car_id and write it like:$_SESSION['info'][]=array(....);

I found each time the page refreshed the session id increment by one value. Or whenever I use array_push to add more item the main session id will increase.

1. Now how to enable the same car id chosen as many times as wanted by user?
2. which will also be linked with sub arrays to identify the specific item each time array_push used to add more variables into the session?
3. How to prevent page reload increase the session id?

Answer (score 0):

for this "How to prevent page reload increase the session id?" 
check in php.ini if session.use_trans_sid is enabled. make it disabled so each time session id will not increase with page load.

Comment: ,I checked but it's disabled by default.